# Drag Node (Label) inside JFXPanel only

Tags: javafx

I am trying to Drag my Label inside my Container only.
Scenario : I  have number of labels which holds single character on it with different color. i want to drag labels but if my label is end it not dragged it should be fitted with panel not move to right.
ex  :
 i have 10 labels at a time 5 label placed in container when i dragged the remaining 5 should be displayed but last label dragged it should be stopped to dragging and now i have last 5 labels in my container ..
So how i can do it....

Edited :
Labels :---->not dragged if its start set to start of container  as well as not dragged <------ reach at the end of labels
 A,B,C,D,E,FE,F,D,FE,DF,DF,DF,WE,WWE,F,F,F,F,F,FS,S,S,S,S,G,GG,.....,

i have labels but if labels reach at its end it not drag (<-----not drag in arrow direction fit with container as well as its start from 1st label start position of container couldn't drag in ----> direction because there is no any labels further.

Comment: You should post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate your issue.

Comment: Just check the bounds in the drag handler of the code I posted in your other question.

Comment: @Roland set Bounds for Container which holds drag gable node ...?